# Model Design in Django

Tags: django, database, django-models, database-design

I have many components and I want to have for each component a list where it shows which users have taken that component and how many of them?

```
class Component(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=128,unique=False,blank=False)
    detail=models.TextField()
    max_num=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    issued_num=models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().save(args,kwargs)

    def available(self):
        return self.max_num-self.issued_num

Status=((0,"Pending"),(1,"Accepted"),(2,"Rejected"))

class Issued(models.Model):
    request_user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    component=models.ForeignKey(Component,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status=models.IntegerField(choices=Status,default=0)
    request_num=models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.component.name
```

I have come up with this solution where Issued model depending on status will be shown as request or will be treated confirmation for issue request depending on its status

Can anyone please tell whether its right way to do it or if its not suggest database friendly design

Comment: Looks good to me. You can add a ManyToMany field to User with through as Issued in the Component model, to make it simpler to query using the models, the database would look the same though. check this in the documentation [ManyToManyField.through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a m2m field here because every Issue has only one user

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks for the suggestion I'll look into it

Comment: @CosmicReindeer I did not mean a m2m between issue and user. I meant a m2m between user and component with the Issue being the through model. The OP is already doing this only the m2m is not specified directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather make issued_num a property of the model and use backwards-relation to determine it's value.

```py
class Component(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=128,unique=False,blank=False)
    detail=models.TextField()
    max_num=models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    issued_num(self):
    # self.issue_set returns a queryset
    return self.issue_set.count()

    @property
    def available(self):
        return self.max_num - self.issued_num

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # override save method to check for issue overflows
    if self.max_num <= self.issued_num:
        raise ValidationError('max issues reached')

class Issue(models.Model):
    Status=((0,"Pending"),(1,"Accepted"),(2,"Rejected"))

    request_user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    component=models.ForeignKey(Component,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status=models.IntegerField(choices=Status,default=0)
    request_num=models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.component.name
```

This way, you don't need to update the issued_num field every time you create an issue object. This means less trips to the database.

You can read more about following backward-relations [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).